# Install multiple versions of CUDA and cuDNN

Tags: cuda

I am currently using CUDA version 7.5 with cuDNN version 5 for MatConvNet. I'd like to install version 8.0 and cuDNN version 5.1 and I want to know if there will be any conflicts if I have the environment paths pointing to both versions of CUDAand cuDNN.

Answer (score 16):

The only [environment variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup) that matter are `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There shouldn't be any conflicts due to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` since all the libs' sonames seem to be bumped properly in each version. As for `PATH`, the shell will execute the version from the path that appears first in the variable. So there is no point for `PATH` to contain both versions at the same time, you'll need to decide which version to use at a time.

Comment: There are two folders in the cudnn directory `lib64` and `include`. To which of these should I set the respective variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 13):

There's a good [article](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/multiple-version-of-cuda-libraries-on-the-same-machine-b9502d50ae77) that describes all the steps. The important ones for me were:

- Run the CUDA install script with the `--silent --toolkit --override` options.
- Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64`.
- Change the `/usr/local/cuda` symbolic link to point back to the default version.

Comment: this works.. you just download the runfile(local) from nvidia (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) ..the full example command is : `sudo sh cuda-9.1.run --silent --toolkit --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-9.1` ..it worked for me without specifying the toolkit, but i might have got other packages (without --silent a text menu will list them).. also I didnt set LD path yet, and the symlink was automatically changed.. i had to `mount --bind /media/user/large /tmp` to give /tmp enough space (~15GB?)..then `umount -l /tmp`

Comment: specifying the toolkit flag and toolkit location still installed 7GB for cuda11.8.. i dont think it changed my driver.. but it did wipe nvcc in my path which needed to be set again.