# Issues installing Pytorch geometric

Tags: pytorch, conda, archlinux, pytorch-geometric

I'm using Arch Linux and I'm trying to install Pytorch geometric via conda. The installation process fails.

I followed the instructions and I managed to install Pytorch in a separate Python environment that I previously created with the following commands

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

and all seems fine. I tried to import torch library in a testing python script and it works.

When I try to install PyTorch geometric with

```
conda install pyg -c pyg
```

I got the following problem:

```
conda install pyg -c pyg                                                            

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/repodata/__init__.py", line 132, in conda_http_errors
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/repodata/__init__.py", line 101, in repodata
        response.raise_for_status()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://conda.anaconda.org/pyg/linux-64/current_repodata.json
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
        return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 372, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in raw_decode
        return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
    simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 91, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 109, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 264, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 132, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 175, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 280, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 84, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 447, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1060, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 267, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 124, in query_all
        result = tuple(chain.from_iterable(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 621, in result_iterator
        yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 319, in _result_or_cancel
        return fut.result(timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 113, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 129, in query
        self.load()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 215, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 323, in _load
        raw_repodata_str = self._repo.repodata(mod_etag_headers)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/repodata/__init__.py", line 94, in repodata
        with conda_http_errors(self._url, filename):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/repodata/__init__.py", line 179, in conda_http_errors
        raise RepodataIsEmpty(
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 461, in __init__
        body = response.json()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
        raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
    requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

`$ /usr/bin/conda install pyg -c pyg`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=myenv
                CONDA_EXE=/usr/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/massimo/.conda/envs/myenv
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(myenv)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/usr/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/usr
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                CUDA_PATH=/opt/cuda
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                     PATH=/home/massimo/.conda/envs/myenv/bin:/usr/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/
                          bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/cuda/bin:/opt
                          /cuda/nsight_compute:/opt/cuda/nsight_systems/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/
                          usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : myenv
    active env location : /home/massimo/.conda/envs/myenv
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/massimo/.condarc
 populated config files : /etc/conda/condarc
                          /home/massimo/.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.9.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=12.0=0
                          __glibc=2.37=0
                          __linux=6.2.5=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /usr  (read only)
      conda av data dir : /usr/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/pyg/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pyg/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/massimo/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/massimo/.conda/envs
                          /usr/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.2 CPython/3.10.9 Linux/6.2.5-arch1-1 arch/rolling glibc/2.37
                UID:GID : 1000:985
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
```

I can't understand what the problem could be. Maybe I have cuda 12.1 installed on the system and it should be downgraded to 11.7, but isn't this a problem that virtual environments should solve?

Answer (score 0):

More than a comment, less than  an answer:

The short answer to your question is no, python virtual environments manage python packages and their dependencies but in general do not effectively manager lower level (system and os-level) software packages. So if your package interfaces closely with any of these lower-level packages such as CUDA, you'll need to manage these packages separately. (Try installing OpenCV with python bindings and CUDA and FFMPEG enabled and one week of headaches later you will understand what I mean.) Docker and other container-based systems solve some of these os-package-level problems but Nvidia Docker still requires you to install CUDA externally to Docker.

So, in general, no. All that aside, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lu2DzaqBeDg) was quite helpful to me when dealing with bothersome installs of pytorch geometric, and if you end up needing multiple versions of CUDA to make this work, there is precedent for this and the issue is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330798/install-multiple-versions-of-cuda-and-cudnn).